# Why doesn't Python have multiline comments?

Tags: python, comments, multiline

OK, I'm aware that triple-quotes strings can serve as multiline comments. For example,

```
"""Hello, I am a 
   multiline comment"""
```

and

```
'''Hello, I am a 
   multiline comment'''
```

But technically speaking these are strings, correct?

I've googled and read the Python style guide, but I was unable to find a technical answer to why there is no formal implementation of multiline, /* */ type of comments. I have no problem using triple quotes, but I am a little curious as to what led to this design decision.

Comment: If you can do it as a string why add more ways?

Comment: Just wanted to add, that it fails if what you are trying to comment happens to also have comments/multi-line strings.  And that of course, is why we need them.

Comment: @S.Lott I think it's a useful question. In order to understand why Python is good, it's important to understand the design decisions that were made (and on-going decisions that are still being made). The question isn't argumentative or combative; it's curious. No need to be so harsh about curiosity.

Comment: The same what if applies of course if your code already has multi-line comments...

Comment: If you need a multi line comment for cod just `if False:` the code

Comment: @Brody Because strings are processed. Comments are ignored. There are problems with using strings as comments. Just look around :)

Comment: @Brody as ADTC said, this doesn't work in many cases. Take sub-line comments: the code `foo(bar /*comment*/, baz)` in any C-like language has no equivalent in Python as a string literal there is a syntax error.

Comment: @Oliver But of course! The idiomatic way to comment out a block in C/C++ is `#if 0`…`#endif`.

Comment: @AturSams, and then reindent the commented out code following `if False:`. Thanks, but no. I understand I'm continuing where you left off 8 years ago, but what is indeed telling, is that your comment got 8 upvotes. I interpret this relatively high number as some people having literally _fallen in love_ with Python to the degree of losing their mind...

Answer (score 288, accepted):

I doubt you'll get a better answer than, "Guido didn't feel the need for multi-line comments".

Guido has [tweeted](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248) about this:

> Python tip: You can use multi-line strings as multi-line comments. Unless used as docstrings, they generate no code! :-)

Comment: See [Guido's tweet](https://twitter.com/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248) on this.

Comment: one disadvantage of mix multi-line string and block comments is IDE has no idea what you want thus can't show comment in different style as needed.

Comment: It also makes it impossible to comment out code with multi-line strings (and can lead to indentation errors if you're not careful). Ew!

Comment: I have worked in a lot of fields where if your code contains commented out code then your code is rejected and you may even find yourself invited to update your CV. Either remove the code that is not needed, not a problem if the code is under version control, or use `if False:` before the code that needs to be disabled.

Comment: @SteveBarnes agree that big blocks of commented-out code in production are bad.  But I don't understand why `if False` is better.  It accomplishes exactly the same thing, while being less clear (since it isn't as obvious at a glance that the block of code has been disabled).

Comment: @dan1111 - I personally prefer removing vestigial code you can always get it back from the VCS if needed. Comments should be comments.

Comment: @SteveBarnes yes I agree (though commenting out temporarily can be useful during the development process).  But given that someone is commenting out a block of code.  I'm not sure why `if false` is better.

Comment: Some prefer if False: # with a comment why - as it is clearly code that is not to be executed but is not confused with comments. A lot of IDEs do allow you to toggle commenting of a block of code on or off.

Comment: @SteveBarnes  Thanks for deciding these things for us under all circumstances  - just like Guido does.  I have worked at the largest companies and there are times and places for this degree of strictness. And not..

Comment: @javadba - Honoured that I may be to be compared to Guido I was not attempting to dictate but rather to explain the reasoning behind the decision. In some of the industries that I have worked in commented out code is a rejection reason - then again code that is never executed & tested is as well - there are MISRA rules against both for example.

Comment: @SteveBarnes  It is disallowed @ google: I think i'm getting a little over excited here: you're correct in this.

Answer (score 61):

Multi-line comments are easily breakable.  What if you have the following in a simple calculator program?

```
operation = ''
print("Pick an operation:  +-*/")
# Get user input here
```

Try to comment that with a multi-line comment:

```
/*
operation = ''
print("Pick an operation:  +-*/")
# Get user input here
*/
```

Oops, your string contains the end comment delimiter.

Comment: The nicest thing about this answer is how it is handled by SO's syntax highlighter.

Comment: I didn't even notice... I rest my case.  :)

Comment: This is one of the many reasons why we have escape characters, I don't see that as a good reason to NOT have support for multi-line comments.

Comment: No escape characters would help here.  If the */ in the string is escaped to allow the comment, it would show up in the string when it's **not** commented.  Otherwise it breaks the comment.  If you want to add even more escapes to strings to allow for comments, I think that would add unnecessary complexity to the language's string syntax.

Comment: I don't understand your logic - perhaps my comment wasn't clear enough. If we used \ as an escape character:
print("Pick an operation:  +-*\/")
"*/" no longer denotes a ending comment block as literally / will be printed. Go ahead and test this in C++. In fact SO's syntax highlighter will show that is valid. This is not a complex subject, it has existed for years in other languages. I would ask that you update your post to include the use of escape characters to show that you CAN use "*/" in your code.

Comment: @NathanAdams: Yes, and now you've introduced another escape character into strings that you have to use *only* because multi-line commenting sucks, just like I said.  And what about raw strings?  Do those get the escape too (which would be the ONLY escape they'd have), or are they still broken?

Comment: What other characters does one need to escape in a multi-line comment?

Comment: what if your code contains ''' . oops your code contains the end comment delimiter

Comment: Multi-line comments aren't inherently breakable; it's just that most implementations of them are (including Python's).  The obvious way to do multi-line comments in Python, to my mind, is to just let me start a comment block with `#:` and use indentation to show when the comment's ended.  It's clean, consistent, and handles nesting perfectly.

Comment: in D you can use /+ +/ *shameless ads*

Comment: Some explanation for questioning minds: Sure this will spoil multiline comment as parser is in "looking for closing \*/" mode (so to speak) after first encountering '/*'. However - if you place opening '/*' in your string - all will work fine and comment will not be messed up.

Comment: That is a contrived example

Comment: -1.  This problem was solved in C, or maybe one of its predecessors.  So from 1972 onwards, this answer has been invalid.

Comment: I would argue that any single-line commenting syntax is also just as "easily breakable" by new line characters... (?) -- I mean... if we're talking extremely minor, rare, and addressable edge cases...

Answer (score 41):

Triple-quoted text should NOT be considered multi-line comments; by convention, they are [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#rationale). They should describe what your code does and how to use it, but not for things like commenting out blocks of code.

According to Guido, [multiline comments in Python are just contiguous single-line comments](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (search for "block comments").

To comment blocks of code, I sometimes use the following pattern:

```
if False:
    # A bunch of code
```

Comment: Seems like Guido [chanded his mind](https://twitter.com/#!/gvanrossum/status/112670605505077248) since then.

Comment: regarding the "if false:" solution, the thing is that in python as it works with tabs, you'd have to tab in all the code under the "if False:". And untab the chunk afterwards. So you'd have to be pretty nifty with your text editor.

Comment: if you use a decent editor, that should be the same amount of time as */

Comment: @barlop yup - learn your editors! This is typically achievable in under a second in vim with `V}>>`

Comment: Multi-line/triple-quoted strings don't have to be docstrings, and vice versa. A docstring is *"a string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition"*, whether or not it's multi-line. Unused (unassigned or not otherwise used in a statement/expression) literals elsewhere in your code, string or otherwise, are discarded at compile time.

Answer (score 32):

This likely goes back to the core concept that there should be one obvious way to do a task.  Additional comment styles add unnecessary complications and could decrease readability.

Comment: That's the issue, I believe: Using a string as a comment is not obvious and violates the "one way to do a task" principle, since there are two ways to do comments: strings and `#`.

Comment: But its not significantly different than what you have in C-based languages: /* vs // , so i don't see how its significantly worse.

Comment: // , Consider WHY someone would want a multi-line comment. Good reasons: ... I can't really think of any beyond "I don't have to type as many of these # doohickeys" and "I need to display this particular comment in a very precise way, and that precise way doesn't allow for preceding #." Say someone wants to do an ASCII diagram, or put some reference javascript code to be copied and pasted if a specific problem comes up. The one obvious way to do a task, here, doesn't cover the edge cases of that task. I agree, though, that additional comment styles are BAD.

Comment: "I don't have to type as many of these # doohickeys". That is precisely why pretty much all languages have block comments (/* ..*/). Believe it or not, but I like to document what my code does: the inputs, the outputs, the algorithms used, the parameters ... That is a lot of text that also gets modified. The restriction to only single-line comments is just plain ridiculous. Note that I do NOT advocate the approach for commenting out code - although that is often handy when trying alternate approaches, as long as the well known possible side effects are understood.

Comment: The other thing I resent about python is that it is essentially a one-man designed language. Whatever Guido says is the truth ... So we have all those odd incompatibilities between language versions. Why ? Because Guido said so ...

Answer (score 12):

Well, the triple-quotes are used as multiline comments in docstrings. And # comments are used as inline comments and people get use to it.

Most of script languages don't have multiline comments either. Maybe that's the cause?

See [PEP 0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), section *Comments*

And see if your Python editor offers some keyboard shortcut for block commenting. Emacs supports it, as well as Eclipse, presumably most of decent IDEs does.

Answer (score 9):

From [The Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/):

There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: Yet Python doesn't follow this at all.. 4 different ways to exit a program for example. Many other examples.

Answer (score 7):

To comment out a block of code in the [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/commenting-and-uncommenting-blocks-of-code.html) IDE:

- Code | Comment with Line Comment
- Windows or Linux: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>
- Mac OS: <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Personally my comment style in say Java is like

```
/*
 * My multi-line comment in Java
 */
```

So having single-line only comments isn't such a bad thing if your style is typical to the preceding example because in comparison you'd have

```
#
# My multi-line comment in Python
#
```

VB.NET is also a language with single-line only commenting, and personally I find it annoying as comments end up looking less likes comments and more like some kind of quote

```
'
' This is a VB.NET example
'
```

Single-line-only comments end up having less character-usage than multi-line comments, and are less likely to be escaped by some dodgy characters in a regex statement perhaps?  I'd tend to agree with Ned though.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for multi-line comments in Python - using the triple quote format can have some problematic consequences, as I've just learned the hard way. Consider this:

```
this_dict = {
    'name': 'Bob',
    
"""
This is a multiline comment in the middle of a dictionary
"""
    
    'species': 'Cat'
}
```

The multi-line comment will be tucked into the next string, messing up the
`'species'` key. Better to just use `#` for comments.

[EDITED: of course, for the intended use of triple quotes, which is for docstrings, this is not a consideration]

Comment: This is the reason why we need multiple line syntax. Why doesn't Guido feel the need to do that?

Comment: @Ooker a normal IDE can just comment out multiple line in one click, as other have pointed out (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/29478739/8874696), so the whole thing is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

```
# This
# is
# a 
# multi-line
# comment
```

Use comment block or search and replace (s/^/#/g) in your editor to achieve this.

Comment: Editing macros aren't well known, which is why  /* */ is useful: it is _meant_ for spanning multiple lines.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by downloading a macro for my text editor (TextPad) that lets me highlight lines and it then inserts # at the first of each line.  A similar macro removes the #'s.  Some may ask why multiline is necessary but it comes in handy when you're trying to "turn off" a block of code for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There should only be one way to do a thing, is contradicted by the usage of multiline strings and single line strings or switch/case and if, different form of loops.

Multiline comments are a pretty common feature and lets face it the multiline string comment is a hack with negative sideffects!
I have seen lots of code doing the multiline comment trick and even editors use it.

But I guess every language has its quirks where the devs insist on never fixing it. I know such quirks from the java side as well, which have been open since the late 90s, never to be fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Assume that they were just considered unnecessary. Since it's so easy to just type `#a comment`, multiline comments can just consist of many single line comments.

For [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), on the other hand, there's more of a need for multiliners. It's harder to keep typing `<!--comments like this-->`.

Comment: this is not the point - there are obvious use cases for both single line and multi line comments. I have used them both extensively in other languages (though I know python purists don't care about other languages). ;)

Comment: try doing this with 200 lines of code, that you have to take out, put back in, then take out again.  Typing 200 initial #'s gets old real fast.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess .. but

Because they are strings, they have some semantic value (the compiler doesn't get rid of them), therefore it makes sense for them to be used as docstrings. They actually become part of the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), so extracting documentation becomes easier.

Answer (score 0):

Because the # convention is a common one, and there really isn't anything you can do with a multiline comment that you can't with a #-sign comment.  It's a historical accident, like the ancestry of `/* ... */` comments going back to PL/I,

Answer (score 0):

Besides, [multiline comments are a bitch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amores_perros). Sorry to say, but regardless of the language, I don't use them for anything else than debugging purposes. Say you have code like this:

```
void someFunction()
{
    Something
    /*Some comments*/
    Something else
}
```

Then you find out that there is something in your code you can't fix with the debugger, so you start manually debugging it by commenting out smaller and smaller chuncks of code with theese multiline comments. This would then give the function:

```
void someFunction()
{ /*
    Something
   /* Comments */
   Something more*/
}
```

This is really irritating.

Comment: uh great, but Python doesn't have `/*`-style comments.

Comment: Right, since python doesn't have real multiline comments it was kind of hard giving examples in python.

Comment: I personally don't understand the problem. Just delete the extra */. Or use // to comment out single lines if you need to be precise.

Comment: There are several languages (many of them functional for whatever reason) which allow nested comments. Search for "nested" in http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Comments for examples.

Comment: well yeah it would be irritating to put a multi-line comment in a multi-line comment.  And while I only remember a bit of my program at a time, I at least remember which part of my program I am looking at and so which I have commented out. But if you can't even remember that, then, you can use the fact that some IDEs make italic what is a comment. Anyhow obviously for such a tiny function, you may as well use single line comments. But if commenting out a big chunk of program, you need a multi-line comment really. or a text editor with that feature.

Answer (score 0):

Multiline comments using **[IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29)** on:

- **Mac OS X**, after code selection, comment a block of code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and uncomment using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.
- **Windows**, after code selection, 
  comment a block of code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and uncomment using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>At</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>.

Comment: Now, for windows, the shortcuts is Alt +3 to comment, and Alt + 4 to uncomment

Answer (score -1):

I remember reading about one guy who would put his multi-line comments into a triple-quoted variable:

```
x = '''
This is my
super-long mega-comment.
Wow there are a lot of lines
going on here!
'''
```

This does take up a bit of memory, but it gives you multi-line comment functionality, and plus most editors will highlight the syntax for you :)

It's also easy to comment out code by simply wrapping it with

```
x = '''
```

and

```
'''
```

Comment: remove the `x =` and it doesn't take up any memory.