# Is it possible to block comment Python code in TextWrangler

Tags: python, textwrangler

I am using the excellent "Learn Python The Hard Way" tutorials and i am wondering does anyone know if its possible to create block comments in it? I note from a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675442/comment-out-a-python-code-block) that it does not seem to be possible in Python but that some editors have implemented methods to do it.

EDIT
I have edited the above question to provide more detail and to use the term "block comment" insted of "block quote"

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by 'block quotes'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate question: [Commenting/Uncommenting a block of Python code in TextWrangler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643251/commenting-uncommenting-a-block-of-python-code-in-textwrangler)

However, I recommend you not bother with those 9 steps and instead just download [sublime text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2).

It is an excellent editor for Python (I believe that's the language its written in, in fact.) and you can accomplish what you're looking for by simply highlighting the code block and using the comment/uncomment keyboard shortcut: `Ctrl+Shift+/`

Comment: Actually, since python doesn't have a special syntax for block comment, simply do Ctrl+/ will comment out all the selected lines.

Comment: Thanks, ill check Sublime Text out

Comment: I just discovered that in Eclipse PyDev it is possible to do this by highlighting the selected text and hitting `CMD` and `4`

Answer (score 2):

In textwrangler on a mac, this worked for me. Highlight the text you want to comment out. Hold down the Command Key and hit /.