# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, comments

What is causing this error? Isn't it possible commenting out lines like this inside code?

```
for i in (Class_1, """Class_2, Class_3"""):
    name = i.__name__
```

`Class_1`, `Class_2` and `Class_3` are classes declared before the upper code.

Error output:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in <module>
    name = i.__name__
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '__name__'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

> Error message line edited to fit the example code

Comment: This question is off-topic. The error message is just a consequence of trying to use a block comment in Python. These would've solved my issue: [Is there a way to create multiline comments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696924/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiline-comments-in-python) and [How to comment out a block of code in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675442/how-to-comment-out-a-block-of-code-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the triple-quoted string `"""Class_2, Class_3"""` to avoid iterating over it which is what you're doing in this case so it looks like `for i in (Class_1,)` (parenthesis are optional).

It seems you want to comment out those unnecessary sides, but please note that those triple-quotes strings technically aren't comments, so they can still affect the script in some areas you didn't intend.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by

```
for i in (Class_1, """Class_2, Class_3"""):
```

When you iterate over this tuple, the second element is a string, thus causing the error.