# How to comment any part of a line

Tags: python, ruby

In C-family languages, we can add a comment inside a line like:

```
public void my_function(/*int a,*/ int b)
```

I can't find a way to do so in Ruby and Python, only at the end of a line:

```
def my_function(a#, b)
```

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/5617169/624886 answers it already.  The answer is NO for Python.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about Ruby too.
And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617159 has advice how to get around this impossibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that in Ruby.