# How to comment out a chunk of a single line of code in python?

Tags: python, comments

In languages like PHP we can do the following:

```php
>>> echo "cat is"." not"." dead"
cat is not dead

>>> echo "cat is"/*." not"*/." dead"
cat is dead
```

What I have done on the second line is, commenting out a chunk of it using PHP's multi-line comment feature.

Please let me know how to do the same in Python without breaking the line of code into separate lines.

Thanks..!

Comment: You cannot do this in Python.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny on that question, one answer is "No" and the other answer expects you to break down the statement in to multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, so the answer is "No, not unless you break it out into multiple lines and comment each line", which I suspect, you still take to mean "No".

Comment: First answer is correct, second is a work around.

Comment: I suppose that's one thing you can't do in Python then. Thank you for the comments..!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, no. To keep old code around, duplicate the line, comment out one, and modify the other.

Comment: This question is already marked as duplicate. But for me, I think your solution works better than the solutions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617159/mid-line-comment-in-python Thanks..!