# Why do interpreted/scripting languages rarely have multi-line comments?

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, comments, interpreted-language

Of the interpreted languages I know (Python, Perl, R, bash), multi-line comments seem to usually involve some misuse of another feature of the language (e.g. multiline strings).

Is there something inherent to the type of parsing which interpreters do that makes multiline comments hard? It doesn't seem like it should be significantly different from, say, multiline strings.

Answer (score 1):

In truth, I'm sure there is no significance when it comes to implementing any form of multi-line comments (based on the methods that most parsers utilize to read/execute the script). In my personal opinion, scripts need multi-line comments the most because of distribution and explanation (most high level languages are usually compiled and only a percentage of it is open sourced anyways). I do know that Lua, a scripting language, does provide multi-line comments:

```
--[==[
COMMENT
]==]--
```

I'm sure it's just a fluke that many languages don't support this. It is commonly acceptable to just use single line comments to create a multi-line comment.

```
//*****************************************\\
//**                                     **\\
//**            JOHN SMITH               **\\
//**        COPYRIGHT 2008-2011          **\\
//**                                     **\\
//*****************************************\\
```

Lots of people will also utilize single line comments to create a cool image (ASCII ART) using the comment character to start off the image (kind of what is displayed above, where `//` is the commenting character(s)/phrase).

Comment: Yeah, but that style commenting just makes more work than anything else. I'd rather not pay devs significant money just to keep comments like that looking proper. C style multiline comments are far preferable IMO

Comment: @drventure  Very very true!  But how much more work?  How often do you actually need to include a multi-lined comment?  Usually once at the beginning of a code snippet or a couple in a larger application.  In truth, it would probably only save you a fraction of time and the result is the same.  Does it actually matter that much?  I fully approve multi-lined comments, but I wouldn't nag a developer to add them in.  Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no reason for scripting languages to not support multiline comments. JavaScript, Groovy, Lua, PHP, REXX, Smalltalk, and Dart all support multiline comments.

Answer (score 0):

In Python we simply use a multiline string as a comment.

Why have two kinds of syntax when one will do?

Comment: Maybe that works for Python, but Perl usually has the philosophy that two ways are better than one. And even Python usually lets you do the same thing in two different ways if that increases clarity. (Having a string which is assigned to nothing be equivalent to a comment is not obvious to me, at least.)

Comment: @Xodarap: I wasn't answering for other languages.  I was answering for Python.  Your question may be too broad to have any possible answer, since the answer is likely to be **different** for each language.

Answer (score 0):

Not all interpreted languages lack multi-line comments. Ruby, for example, has them.

I suspect this is largely the preference of the language designer. Some just don't see multi-line comments as a necessary feature. (Many code editors these days offer shortcuts that comment/uncomment large blocks of code using single-line comments.)

Also, multi-line comments add complexity to a parser. It has to deal with the possibility of nested comments, for example. Why add complexity if you don't have to?

Comment: "Why add complexity if you don't have to".... But that's the whole point of multiline comments, to remove the complexity of having to deal with multiple single line comments. better to have the compiler/interpreter deal with it than the developer.

Comment: I don't see multiline comments as being simpler for anyone. Scripting languages often have 1 character, e.g. `#` that means a start of a comment on a line. That's simple. Simple to implement in a parser, simple for programmers to remember, simple for non-programmers to remember. Simple to grep in comments or omit if you don't  to grep in comments). No need to add complexity with little gain.

Comment: @nos, @vocaro: Languages with multiline comments usually don't allow them to be nested. So multiline comments are regular and hence equivalent to single-line comments (i.e. terminal in the CFG). I don't think it would make the parser significantly more complex.

Comment: If the parser doesn't have the ability to do multi-lined comments, then it was written bad (for a parser).  The way parsers work (well, most anyways), would make it extremely easy (within reason) to add multi-lined comments.

Comment: Unless your multiline comments nest, the parser won't even see them, just the lexer. Given that, it isn't any harder to lex multiline comments than single-line ones.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's just a bit of language bias. C style multiline comments tend to show up in c-esque languages, but most other langs don't have an equivalent.

As for the parsers themselves. There's no reason I can think of that parsers don't implement multi line comments, other than that the lang designer just didn't want to. Most parser generators can easily handle the construct.

Comment: Non-C-style languages have multiline comments too though: OCaml has `(* .. *)`, Haskell has `{- .. -}`...

Comment: True enough, and I believe someone mentioned that Ruby does too. But I'd hardly consider OCaml or Haskell as mainstream, and I've never heard of them being embedded in any case. But, it's entirely possible I've just never run across any projects that do.

Answer (score 0):

There are two wrong assumptions in your question.

The first wrong assumption is that “interpreted/scripting languages rarely have multi-line comments”. You're suffering from confirmation bias. There are compiled languages with single-line comments (e.g. Fortran, many Lisp dialects) and interpreted languages with multi-line comments (e.g. Perl, Python).

The second wrong assumption is that “misuse of another feature” is involved. Languages are better designed as a whole, there's no need to introduce an extra feature for multiline comments if some feature that exists anyway will do the trick. For example, in Python, multiline strings exist, and an instruction consisting only of a string is a no-op, so multiline strings make fine comments. In Perl, one way to have multiline comments is through [Pod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html), a documentation format; comments are a kind of documentation, so it's quite natural to use `=pod … =cut` for multiline comments (multiline strings, through [here documents](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF) `<<'EOF'; … EOF`, are another method).

Comment: Oh come on. Are you going to sit there with a straight face and tell me that Larry Wall excluded multiline comments because then [Perl would have multiple ways of doing the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There%27s_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)?

Comment: @Xodarap: Absolutely. Being a champion of the [first virtue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer), Larry Wall didn't bother to add an extra feature if there was some other way to get it.

Comment: *interpreted languages with multi-line comments (e.g. Perl, Python)* — I don't know about Perl, but [Python doesn't have multi-line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/397148/3416774). [Multi-line strings are not multi-line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28212280/3416774)