# Why is using multiline comment not allowed in the middile of if statement?

Tags: python, comments

This code yields `invalid syntax`:

```
a = 'hi'
""" comment 1 """
if a == 'hi':
    print(a)

""" comment 2 """
elif a != 'hi':
    print('hello')
```

However this works:

```
a = 'hi'
# comment 1
if a == 'hi':
    print(a)

# comment 2
elif a != 'hi':
    print('hello')
```

Do you know why is that?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212280/python-programming-multiline-comments-before-an-else-statement

Comment: Python doesn't really have multiline comments, it's a string.