# Ending a comment in Python

Tags: python

*I have already read this: [Why doesn't Python have multiline comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397148/why-doesnt-python-have-multiline-comments)*

So in my IDLE , I wrote a comment:

```
Hello#World
```

Anything after the d of world is also a part of the comment.In c++ , I am aware of a way to close the comment like:

```
/*Mycomment*/
```

Is there a way to end a comment in Python?

***NOTE:*** I would not prefer not to use the triple quotes.

Comment: No, there isn't. Why would you want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already read there are no multiline comments, only single line. Comments cause Python to ignore everything until the end of the line. You "close" them with a newline!

I don't particularly like it, but some people use multiline *strings* as comments. Since you're just throwing away the value, you can approximate a comment this way. The only time it's really doing anything is when it's the first line in a function or class block, in which case it is treated as a [docstring](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Also, this may be more of a shell scripting convention, but what's so bad about using multiple single line comments?

```
#####################################################################
# It is perfectly fine and natural to write "multi-line" comments   #
# using multiple single line comments. Some people even draw boxes  #
# with them!                                                        #
#####################################################################
```

Comment: "Since you're just producing a value and then throwing it away": FWIW, you're not producing a value in CPython -- non-docstring string literals generate no bytecode.

Comment: Point taken. Poor word choice, perhaps? To me, it feels unusual to have a literal in a program that is not named or used. Maybe that's just a style thing. That's all I meant, in any case. @DSM Updated wording.

Comment: @DSM: No byte-code is produced, but the byte code compiler "wastes" time and resources processing the multi-line string literal before throwing it away (assuming it wasn't a docstring). Personally that doesn't bother me much especially since Python uses multi-line string literals for precisely this purpose (commenting code) itself and that most modules are only compiled the first time they're encountered.

Comment: @martineau: given that Guido himself has endorsed it, I think we're on safe ground in doing so. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't close a comment in python other than by ending the line.

There are number of things you can do to provide a comment in the middle of an expression or statement, if that's really what you want to do.

First, with functions you annotate arguments -- an annotation can be anything:

```
def func(arg0: "arg0 should be a str or int", arg1: (tuple, list)):
    ...
```

If you start an expression with `(` the expression continues beyond newlines until a matching `)` is encountered. Thus

```
assert (
    str
    # some comment
    .
    # another comment
    join
) == str.join
```

Answer (score 0):

You can emulate comments by using strings. They are not exactly comments, since they execute, but they don't return anything.

```
print("Hello", end = " ");"Comment";print("World!")
```

Answer (score -2):

if you start with triple quotes, end with triple quotes